# Which fuels burn the longest in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What's the order of "best fuels"?

**Example:** Coal cooks less than lava and blaze rods, wood cooks less than coal, etc.

What's the order of fuels based on their 'cooking quantity'?

Comment: Just use stacks of coal, they work the best and you can smelt 8 items with one coal so a total of 512 items with one stack of coal.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Fuel efficiency** found in [Smelting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smelting#Fuel_efficiency)

```
                           Burn Time  Burn Time     Fuel needed to
Fuel                        (ticks)   (smeltings*)  smelt 64 items
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Lava Bucket                  20000         100                0.64
Block of Coal                16000          80                0.8
Blaze Rod                     2400          12                5.3
Coal and Charcoal             1600           8                8
Huge Mushrooms                 300           1.5             43
Wood and wooden things†        300           1.5             43
Daylight Sensors               300           1.5             43
Banners                        300           1.5             43
Wood tools and weapons         200           1               64
Wooden Slabs                   150           0.75            86
Stick                          100           0.5            128
Saplings                       100           0.5            128

* Number of items smelted per fuel item
† Anything mostly crafted from wood: Crafting tables, Chests, Jukebox (Except Slabs)
```

Note that the effective efficiency of the long-burning materials goes down rapidly if you don't restock the furnace.

Comment: Do note that efficiency is not the only thing you should take into account. Renewability (is a resource infinite or not) comes into play too, as well as "obtainability" (how easy is it to get/transport the resource). Lava buckets use iron, which is non-renewable. Blaze rods are infinite, and easily obtainable when you have a blaze spawner.

Comment: Would be awesome if charcoal blocks existed

Comment: @Konerak The bucket is not used up during the smelting process, so the renewability of the 3 iron bars used to make it is of minimal concern for large smelting operations - in reality you're much more likely to run out of lava.

Comment: So, at the risk of stating the obvious: combine your coal into blocks (if you're smelting large quantities that is) and split your wood into sticks before burning it - or better yet convert it to charcoal first.

Comment: @Konerak Iron _is_ renewable, through the use of iron golem farms. However these are impractical to make and are usually mistaken for being unrenewable.

Comment: @Psychemaster: Once I get to the Nether, though, or find some underground lava lakes, lava immediately becomes my prime fuel source. The thing about lava is, besides small single-source-block streams you find in cave tunnels, it _always_ comes in huge quantities.

Answer (score 15):

Sorting the entries in [this table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace#Fuel_efficiency) based on the last column gives this list:

- Lava Bucket
- Block of Coal
- Blaze Rod
- Charcoal
- Coal
- Fence
- Fence Gate
- Wooden Stairs
- Wooden Pressure Plate
- Wood Planks
- Wood
- Chest
- Trapped Chest
- Daylight Sensor
- Bookshelf
- Crafting Table
- Trapdoor
- Huge Mushrooms
- Note Block
- Jukebox
- Wooden Tools and Weapons
- Wooden Slabs
- Stick
- Saplings

Answer (score 7):

Found an even better [list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Furnace)

Under the section "Fuel efficiency"

From most to least efficient (according to new list):

- Lava Bucket
- Block of coal
- Blaze rod
- coal
- charcoal
- Huge Mushrooms
- Note Block
- Jukebox
- Daylight Sensor
- Trapped Chest
- Chest
- Bookshelf
- Crafting table
- Trapdoor
- Wooden Stairs
- Fence Gate
- Fence
- Wooden preasure plate
- Wood
- Wood Planks
- Wooden Tools and Weapons
- Wooden slabs
- Stick
- Saplings

@Meraj99 - Because you can use them as fuel for a furnace xD

Comment: Why are there bookshelves, huge mushroom blocks, swords in the list....

Comment: Burning jukeboxes...it's like a _really efficient_ CD burning. Cast out the devil's music and repent!

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Lava Bucket.

## 2. Block of Coal

## 3. Blaze Rod.

## 4. Coal and Charcoal.

Since Block of Coal is stackable, that makes it a little better than Lava Bucket, because as Celta's answer states that Lava Bucket can cook 100 meat, Block of Coal doing 80. A stack of Block of Coal would be 80x64, doing simple math would tell you that (80x64) is bigger than 100. I hope this helped. (Please don't remove hashtags)

Answer (score 0):

Lava bucket, block of coal, blaze rods, coal and charcoal are the good fuels, however if you are in a survival situation, you may need to use items like saplings and sticks.

Answer (score 0):

1. bucket of lava
2. coal block
3. blaze rod
4. coal/charcoal
5. jukebox
6. note block
7. wood
8. sticks
9. saplings

Comment: ....don't you mean _coal_ block?

Answer (score -2):

Greatest to least: Blaze Rod, Lava Bucket, Coal, Charcoal, Wood, Wooden Planks, Wooden Slabs, Wooden Tools, Saplings.

Comment: Um, that's greatest to least, and the order is kinda wrong.